# Getting frequent "connection timeout" error on Databricks Job while connecting to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, jdbc, clojure, azure-sql-database, databricks

We have a clojure code that runs on Databricks, and fetches some large amount of data from Azure SQL Database.

Recently, we are getting frequent connection timeout errors.

I am new to Clojure, so I don't understand why this error occurs. Sometimes the code runs perfectly while sometimes it fails.

We have tried different connection parameters like "connectionretry" and "logintimeout" but it didn't work.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SimpleInputStream.getBytes(SimpleInputStream.java:352)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:796)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:3777)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2054)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2040)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getObject(SQLServerResultSet.java:2372)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$dft_read_columns$fn__226.invoke(jdbc.clj:457)
    at clojure.core$mapv$fn__6953.invoke(core.clj:6627)
    at clojure.lang.LongRange.reduce(LongRange.java:233)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6544)
    at clojure.core$mapv.invokeStatic(core.clj:6618)
    at clojure.core$mapv.invoke(core.clj:6618)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$dft_read_columns.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:457)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$dft_read_columns.invoke(jdbc.clj:453)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$result_set_seq$row_values__233.invoke(jdbc.clj:483)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$result_set_seq$thisfn__235.invoke(jdbc.clj:493)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$result_set_seq$thisfn__235$fn__236.invoke(jdbc.clj:493)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:521)
    at clojure.core$seq__4357.invokeStatic(core.clj:137)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__4785.invoke(core.clj:2637)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.Cons.next(Cons.java:39)
    at clojure.lang.RT.next(RT.java:688)
    at clojure.core$next__4341.invokeStatic(core.clj:64)
    at clojure.core$dorun.invokeStatic(core.clj:3033)
    at clojure.core$doall.invokeStatic(core.clj:3039)
    at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:3039)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$query$fn__340$fn__341.invoke(jdbc.clj:1007)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$query$fn__340.invoke(jdbc.clj:1006)
```

Comment: This needs more details. If you are using RDBMS, your Clojure code is highly likely to have next.jdbc as the DB client library. You can configure timeout values using 'timeout' as can be found here (https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/src/next/jdbc.clj#:~:text=*%20%60%3Atimeout%60%20%2D%2D%20the%20query%20timeout%2C)

Comment: Some ideas to try:   Since you are sometimes getting the timeout and sometimes not, maybe you are being rate limited by Azure?  Though, I'd expect a different error message if that was the case.  Since you say you are transferring a large amount of data, perhaps there is a session timeout which limits the max time a request can take?  Do you only get the timeout when transferring a large amount of data?  If changing the timeout doesn't work, you could try changing your query to retrieve less data per query?

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't related to Azure SQL Database JDBC driver but the way you are establishing the connection and running queries.

Make sure you are closing the connection properly after every commit. Additionally, you have a sufficient sleep time between connections.

Also, make sure that the large data you are fetching must have required bandwidth and properly queried.

You can refer these official documentation for troubleshooting:

[Troubleshooting connectivity issues and other errors with Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues)

[Resolving connectivity errors to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/resolving-connectivity-errors)